# Gnome Shell has problems sleeping. Why?

Tags: gnome, suspend, intel-graphics, gnome-shell, 18.10

On my laptop (but not the desktop), Gnome Shell has problems sleeping:

- When the screen blanks, Gnome Shell restarts, and wakes the screen back up.
- <s>When the system is awakened from *sleep* (suspend mode), I have to log back in, because Gnome Shell has crashed!</s> This issue no longer happens, but now, the system misbehaves (no wallpaper, tray icons and indicators not visible, arc menu not usuable, etc) if it isn't locked when the screen wakes up, either from suspend, or just from being turned off to save power. To get around this, I have to manually lock and unlock, if screenlocking is not enabled.

I'm running a HP Elitebook 8460p with Intel Graphics.
I tried turning off all extensions, <s>but Gnome Shell still has insomnia</s> but Gnome still misbehaves, especially after waking from sleep.

Other than magical, digital, sleeping pills, what can I do to fix this issue?

Comment: Info about swap?

Comment: @pomsky it's a fresh install, so it's using a swap file.

Comment: Simply install MATE (or Unity) desktop to stop seeing this nightmare :)